# Merging two two nested JSONs in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, json

I have two jsons as follows

JSON 1 -

```
{
"2021-03-11": [
    {
        "14:30:00": 3000
    }
],
"2021-03-14": [
    {
        "14:30:00": 130
    }
]
```

}

JSON 2 -

```
{
"2021-03-02": [
    {
        "10:30:00": null
    }
],
"2021-03-11": [
    {
        "10:30:00": null
    },
    {
        "11:30:00": null
    },
    {
        "14:30:00": null
    }
],
"2021-03-12": [
    {
        "11:30:00": null
    }
],
"2021-03-14": [
    {
        "14:30:00": null
    }
],
"2021-03-15": [
    {
        "10:30:00": null
    }
]
```

}

I want to combine these two JSON like below

```
{
"2021-03-02": [
    {
        "10:30:00": null
    }
],
"2021-03-11": [
    {
        "10:30:00": null
    },
    {
        "11:30:00": null
    },
    {
        "14:30:00": 3000
    }
],
"2021-03-12": [
    {
        "11:30:00": null
    }
],
"2021-03-14": [
    {
        "14:30:00": 130
    }
],
"2021-03-15": [
    {
        "10:30:00": null
    }
]
```

}

But when I use the || operator, this is the result I get

```
{
{
"2021-03-02": [
    {
        "10:30:00": null
    }
],
"2021-03-11": [
    {
        "14:30:00": 3000
    }
],
"2021-03-12": [
    {
        "11:30:00": null
    }
],
"2021-03-14": [
    {
        "14:30:00": 130
    }
],
"2021-03-15": [
    {
        "10:30:00": null
    }
]
```

}

for some reason it only retrieves only one second level key value pair, is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: *for some reason it only retrieves only one second level key value pair* This is a norma: *Concatenating two objects generates an object containing the union of their keys, taking the second object's value when there are duplicate keys.* https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: Concatenation does not iterate over all document strusture, it operates only on the upper level. So you must unnest your JSONs then nest them back.

Comment: Have a look here for a starter: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/287155/postgresql-function-to-automatically-merge-and-add-two-jsonb-values-from-differe   You'll have to add a level to deal with your nesting.

Comment: See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166092) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944888/)